# How to show Head Up Display HUD View in android

Tags: android

I want to show an animated view that is displayed on all app views and this view is also user interactive. Actually, I need to notify user for any update like new message, to show animation on app start up and to congratulate user for any achievement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/marshallino16/FloatingView) is also a better solution for your problem.

Comment: This is helpful for me too.

Comment: please describe the content of the link in a few words to improve your answer. Links only answers are no good practise on SO.

Answer (score 2):

Tooleap SDK can help with it.

http://developer.tooleap.com/

Comment: Great link Thanks a lot. If my reputation were to be 15 or above I may approve your answer but now could not. If you increment up my question I could do that.

Answer (score 0):

yea, but you need to make the Android go to reverse video.